# ReactJS , how to Switching the current Language Flag according to the user choose in changeLanguage()

Tags: reactjs

i am a new on React and i have a React component as in the next code and i cannot find a way to make the currentLanFlag img src to be dynamic and follow the user choose in the drop down languages menu ......
What i want is : when the user click on the anchor tag German, the img with CLass currentLanFlag to be a German Flag, same for English and the others Languages .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import { translate, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
import de from '../../../assets/img/de.png';
import en from '../../../assets/img/en.png';
import fr from '../../../assets/img/fr.png';
import pt from '../../../assets/img/pt.png';
import ar from '../../../assets/img/ar.GIF';
import '../../../assets/FontAwesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import './topNavComponenets.css';
const { version: appVersion } = require('../../../../package.json');
class TopNavComponenets extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super()
    this.state = {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    }
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    axios.get('api/auth/en/profile',{ withCredentials: true })
      .then(response => this.setState({
        firstName: response.data.firstName,
        lastName: response.data.lastName,
      })); 
  }
  logout () {
    axios.get('api/auth/en/logout',{ withCredentials: true })
  }

  render () {
        const { i18n } = this.props;
        const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
          i18n.changeLanguage(lng);;
        };
        let currentLanFlag = en;

return (
  <div className="topNavComponenets">
    <div className='infoContainer row'>
      < div className="col-12 text-right">
          <div className="userCont col-4">
            <Link to="/user" ><i className="fa fa-user" title={"My Profile"}></i></Link>
                <p className="infos">
                  {this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName} 
                </p>
          </div>

            <div className='version col-4'>
                <div className="dropdown show">
                  <a className="dropdown-toggle" href="" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  <img 
                  className="currentLanFlag" 
                  src={ currentLanFlag } 
                  alt="Language Flag"/>
                  </a>
                  <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                    <a onClick={() => changeLanguage('de')} className="dropdown-item"><img className="flag" src={de} alt=""/><Trans>German</Trans></a>
                    <a onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')} className="dropdown-item"><img className="flag" src={en} alt=""/><Trans>English</Trans></a>
                    <a onClick={() => changeLanguage('fr')} className="dropdown-item"><img className="flag" src={fr} alt=""/><Trans>French</Trans></a>
                    <a onClick={() => changeLanguage('pt')} className="dropdown-item"><img className="flag" src={pt} alt=""/><Trans>Portugues</Trans></a>
                    <a onClick={() => changeLanguage('ar')} className="dropdown-item"><img className="flag" src={ar} alt=""/><Trans>Arabic</Trans></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p title={"CMS Version"}>v.{appVersion}</p>
            </div>

            <div className='buttonContainer col-4'>
              <a href="/login"> <span onClick={this.logout}>
              <i className="fa fa-power-off" title={"Logout"}></i>
              </span></a>
            </div>

        </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
)}} 
export default translate('translations')(TopNavComponenets);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would set currentLanFlag in your state.

```
this.state = {
    ...
    currentLanFlag: 'en'
};
```

Then change your image tag to be something along the lines of

```
<img 
className="currentLanFlag" 
src={ this.state.currentLanFlag } 
alt="Language Flag"/>
```

Your  on click should then change the state of this.state.currentLanFlag.

Something along the lines of

```
// A function
changeLan = (event) {
  this.setState({
    currentLanFlag: event.target.data
  });
  changeLanguage(event.target.data);
}
// in your return
<a data='de' onClick={this.changeLan}><img className="flag" src={de} alt=""/><Trans>German</Trans></a>
```

this.setState will tell react "something changed, rerender" at that point your language flag will be updated to the new flag.

Please note, the above is not tested.

You can find nice documentation here 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Just you need make some minor changes. This is for if you need to switch between two different language.

```
import en from '../../../assets/img/en.png';
import de from '../../../assets/img/de.png';
```

**1. set the current flag in your state**

```
state = {
    currLangFlag: 'en'
}
```

**2. Replace your current event handler with this one**

```
const changeLan = (lng) => {
    this.setState({ currLangFlag: lng })
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng)
}
```

**3. Use the ternary operator you can switch the flag `url` after state update**

```
{currLangFlag === 'en' ? <img src={en} alt={currLangFlag} /> : <img src={de} alt={currLangFlag} />}
```

**4. Call the event handler**

```
<NavLink onClick={() => changeLan('en')} to={this.props.location}>
  <img className="flag" src={en} alt=""/><Trans>English</Trans>
</NavLink >
<NavLink onClick={() => changeLan('de')} to={this.props.location}>
  <img className="flag" src={de} alt=""/><Trans>German</Trans>
</NavLink >
```